# C# how to use a specific method with interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have 2 classes and an interface:
`Program`, `superSecretWork` and `openDoor`.

What I want to do is, whenever my class is using an interface, I want that interface to call a particular method of the class that's inheriting it.

I know I could just use the class `superSecretWork`, but that isn't the point. I might want to inherit another base class but need parts of other classes (used by other interfaces).

Code example:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program: openDoor
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    public interface openDoor
    {
        bool open();
    }
    public class superSecretWork : openDoor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// I only want this method to be used when using the interface
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool open()
        {
            //some custom logic here
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't how interfaces work.

Comment: If you do ` openDoor obj = new superSecretWork();` and call method on `obj` it will call method from `superSecretWork` class. Why didn't you do anything yourself and try to figure out what happens?

Comment: @sty correct me if i'm wrong but isn't that the only way C# handled multiple inheritances?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya not even worth the response, but obviously missed the premise of the question

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if you read ,  I know I could just use the class superSecretWork, but that isn't the point, I might want to inherit another base class but need parts of other classes (used other by interfaces). then i would have followed up with you

Comment: A class doesn't inherit from an interface, it *implements* the interface. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) tells us that interfaces contain "only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers". Interfaces have nothing to do with the implementation. They are merely data passing contracts. They define the *required* members, properties, etc for all classes that implement them. Stuff like calling methods or defining them is completely beyond their scope.

Comment: @sly I get all that, but then how do you inherit multiple base classes?  I'm starting to think C# has no way to do so

Comment: It would be more clear if you add some more details around the same example. Let say there is another class implements the interface. Now what's do you expect to happen in program.cs if interface method is called on an object of that class? Interface doesn't call any of the methods of its implementing classes. Putting some more example code and details would help understanding the question more.

Comment: `how do you inherit multiple base classes?` shouldn't that be the question put in the original post? That's not possible in modern OO languages such as Java and C#. You can do that by having two interfaces implemented in one class and inherit another class from that class that way you have features of both the interfaces.

Comment: "but then how do you inherit multiple base classes" -> what would be the use case for that? A class should of one thing very well, if a class inherits multiple (possible unrelated) classes it would break that idea. You can however create a hierarchical inheritance, eg: MyForm -> Form -> Control.

Comment: "I might want to inherit another base class but need parts of other classes (used other by interfaces)." -> then inherit one class and inject the other classes using dependency injection to access their methods. You need to think different and not fixate on inheritance. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @PeterBons Thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for public Player() : base(new Visible(), new Movable(), new Solid()) { }

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent someone from calling a method on a class without casting it as an interface.

For example:

```
public interface IDoesSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class DoerOfStuff : IDoesSomething

    void DoSomething()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

You can't prevent someone from calling `DoSomething` on an instance of `DoerOfStuff`. The class has that method, so someone can call it.

What you can do is have a class implement multiple interfaces, and cast a class according to the interface that a method should see.

For example:

```
public interface IFryCook
{
    void Fry(FrenchFries fries);
}

public interface IGrillCook
{
    void Grill(Burger burger);
}

public class FastFoodCook : IFryCook, IGrillCook
{
    public void Fry(FrenchFries fries) { }
    public void Grill(Burger burger) { }
}
```

If you do this:

```
public void ProcessFrenchFryOrder(IFryCook frycook)
```

You can pass an instance of `FastFoodCook` to the method, but it will only be "seen" as an instance of `IFryCook`. The method doesn't know that the class also implements other methods.

It's also good to rethink whether you want to use class inheritance. It sounds like that already added some difficulty to your problem. If you have functionality in class `A` that you want in class `B`, inheriting from `A` often causes difficulties. It's better for class `B` to depend on a separate instance of class `A`. The principle is "[favor composition over inheritance](https://codingdelight.com/2014/01/16/favor-composition-over-inheritance-part-1/)." If the way we get classes to work together is by having them inherit from each other then we paint ourselves into a corner because sooner or later we'll want to use functionality from two classes and we can't inherit from them both.